# Cómo validar un RUC de Perú

Tags: javascript, validación, lenguaje-agnóstico

**Pregunta:** ¿Cómo puedo verificar que el formato de un RUC peruano sea válido?

**¿Qué es el RUC?** El [Registro Único de Contribuyentes](http://www.sunat.gob.pe/exportaFacil/ruc.htm) ([RUC](http://www.sunat.gob.pe/exportaFacil/ruc.htm)) es el registro informático donde se encuentran inscriptos los contribuyentes de todo Perú. Es el código tributario de personas y empresas expedido por la [SUNAT](http://www.sunat.gob.pe/) ([Superintendencia Nacional de Aduanas y de Administración Tributaria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superintendencia_Nacional_de_Aduanas_y_de_Administraci%C3%B3n_Tributaria)), con registros desde 1993 y regulado desde 2004 <sup>[[1]](http://www.elperuano.com.pe/NormasElperuano/2015/06/16/1251160-1.html)</sup>.

Es una clave única, de carácter permanente y uso obligatorio, para todas las personas naturales o jurídicas (nacionales o extranjeros) <sup>[[2]](http://www.sunat.gob.pe/legislacion/ruc/)</sup>.
La [SUNAT](http://www.sunat.gob.pe/) mantiene el registro de contribuyentes, asociando al RUC con los datos personales <sup>[[3]](http://mariano.freevar.com/ruc/REGLAMENTO%20DE%20LA%20LEY%20DEL%20RUC.pdf)</sup>.

Cada contribuyente es identificado con un número de 11 dígitos. Los 2 primeros dígitos identifican al tipo de persona, los siguientes 8 son el DNI o el número asignado a la empresa, y el último es un dígito verificador <sup>[[4]](http://conexiontributaria.blogspot.com.ar/2011/10/que-es-la-sunat-que-es-el-ruc-que_9779.html)[[5]](http://www.perucontable.com/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?post_id=57226)</sup>.

[image: 2 ("10" Persona natural, "20" Persona jurídica) + 8 (DNI o número empresa) + 1 (dígito verificador)]

**Qué intenté:** Utilicé [el mismo código que usa la SUNAT](http://www.sunat.gob.pe/a/js/js.js) en su web para validar un RUC. Sin embargo, acepta RUCs incorrectos y parecería tener cálculos redundantes.

```js
//Validación de SUNAT
function valruc(valor){
  valor = trim(valor)
  if ( esnumero( valor ) ) {
    if ( valor.length == 8 ){
      suma = 0
      for (i=0; i<valor.length-1;i++){
        digito = valor.charAt(i) - '0';
        if ( i==0 ) suma += (digito*2)
        else suma += (digito*(valor.length-i))
      }
      resto = suma % 11;
      if ( resto == 1) resto = 11;
      if ( resto + ( valor.charAt( valor.length-1 ) - '0' ) == 11 ){
        return true
      }
    } else if ( valor.length == 11 ){
      suma = 0
      x = 6
      for (i=0; i<valor.length-1;i++){
        if ( i == 4 ) x = 8
        digito = valor.charAt(i) - '0';
        x--
        if ( i==0 ) suma += (digito*x)
        else suma += (digito*x)
      }
      resto = suma % 11;
      resto = 11 - resto
      
      if ( resto >= 10) resto = resto - 10;
      if ( resto == valor.charAt( valor.length-1 ) - '0' ){
        return true
      }      
    }
  }
  return false
}
function trim(cadena){
  cadena2 = "";
  len = cadena.length;
  for ( var i=0; i <= len ; i++ )
    if (cadena.charAt(i) != " "){
      cadena2+=cadena.charAt(i);
    }
  return cadena2;
}
function esnumero(campo){
  return (!(isNaN( campo )));
}



//Prueba
var ruc    = '12345678903',
    valido = valruc(ruc);

console.log('El RUC', ruc,
            'es', (valido?'válido':'inválido'),
            'para SUNAT.');
```

**Objetivo:** Me interesa validar el formato de un RUC ingresado por un usuario, que pueda aceptar caracteres como guiones u otros signos de puntuación entre los dígitos. Lo utilizaría como etapa previa antes de enviar un formulario.
Adicionalmente, si existiera la forma de comprobar si el RUC existe y está activo, sería mejor aún.

Estoy probando en JavaScript, pero puede ser en cualquier lenguaje popular. Lo importante es el algoritmo.

**Pruebas:** Encontré el siguiente listado de empresas manufactureras en [empresas.regioncallao.gob.pe ( PDF)](http://empresas.regioncallao.gob.pe/contenidos/fileCapacitaciones/DIRECTORIO_2010.pdf) que puede utilizarse como datos de prueba.

---

> F̲u̲e̲n̲t̲e̲s̲:
> ① <sub><sup>Decreto Legislativo N° 943 - http://www.elperuano.com.pe/NormasElperuano/2015/06/16/1251160-1.html</sup></sub>
> ② <sub><sup>SUNAT - Registro Único de Contribuyentes - http://www.sunat.gob.pe/legislacion/ruc/</sup></sub>
> ③ <sub><sup>Reglamento de ley del RUC (PDF) - http://mariano.freevar.com/ruc/REGLAMENTO%20DE%20LA%20LEY%20DEL%20RUC.pdf</sup></sub>
>
>
> ④ <sub><sup>¿Qué es la SUNAT? ¿Qué es el RUC? - http://conexiontributaria.blogspot.com.ar/2011/10/que-es-la-sunat-que-es-el-ruc-que_9779.html</sup></sub>
> ⑤ <sub><sup>Foro contable - otros digitos de RUC - http://www.perucontable.com/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?post_id=57226</sup></sub>

Comment: Pregunta y respuesta realizadas [a pedido especial](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33567203#33567203) del amigo @PedroÁvila.

Comment: También pueden consultar cualquier RUC del Perú en la nueva página http://consultaderuc.info/ carga rápido y no tiene captchas.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Código:

Utilizamos 3 funciones (cada una llama a la siguiente si el resultado es válido):

1. **`validarInput(input)`**

   - Elimina signos de puntuación comunes y espacios
   - Verifica que sea un número entero
   - Muestra el resultado con formato
2. **`rucValido(ruc)`**

   - Acepta un RUC como número
   - Verifica que empiece con 10, 15, 16, 17 o 20
   - Comprueba que el dígito verificador corresponda
3. **`obtenerDatosSUNAT(ruc)`**

   - Utiliza el servicio de http://www.wmtechnology.org/Consultar-RUC/ para obtener los datos de la SUNAT
   - Hace una llamada por AJAX y analiza la respuesta para ver si el estado es *activo*.

```js
//Handler para el evento cuando cambia el input
//Elimina cualquier caracter espacio o signos habituales y comprueba validez
function validarInput(input) {
    var ruc       = input.value.replace(/[-.,[\]()\s]+/g,""),
        resultado = document.getElementById("resultado"),
        existente = document.getElementById("existente"),
        valido;
        
    existente.innerHTML = "";
    
    //Es entero?    
    if ((ruc = Number(ruc)) && ruc % 1 === 0
     && rucValido(ruc)) { // ⬅️ ⬅️ ⬅️ ⬅️ Acá se comprueba
     valido = "Válido";
        resultado.classList.add("ok");
        obtenerDatosSUNAT(ruc);
    } else {
        valido = "No válido";
     resultado.classList.remove("ok");
    }
        
    resultado.innerText = "RUC: " + ruc + "\nFormato: " + valido;
}

// Devuelve un booleano si es un RUC válido
// (deben ser 11 dígitos sin otro caracter en el medio)
function rucValido(ruc) {
    //11 dígitos y empieza en 10,15,16,17 o 20
    if (!(ruc >= 1e10 && ruc < 11e9
       || ruc >= 15e9 && ruc < 18e9
       || ruc >= 2e10 && ruc < 21e9))
        return false;
    
    for (var suma = -(ruc%10<2), i = 0; i<11; i++, ruc = ruc/10|0)
        suma += (ruc % 10) * (i % 7 + (i/7|0) + 1);
    return suma % 11 === 0;
    
}

//Buscar datos del RUC y si existe
function obtenerDatosSUNAT(ruc) {
    //Init
    var url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/wmtechnology.org/Consultar-RUC/?modo=1&btnBuscar=Buscar&nruc=" + ruc,
        existente = document.getElementById("existente"),
        xhr = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) //Crear XHR
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    else return false;
    //handler para respuesta
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) { //200 OK
            var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument()
                    .documentElement,
                res = "",
                txt, campos,
                ok = false;
                
            doc.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            //Sólo el texto de las clases que nos interesa
            campos = doc.querySelectorAll(".list-group-item");
            if (campos.length) {
                for (txt of campos)
                    res += txt.innerText + "\n";
                //eliminar blancos por demás
                res = res.replace(/^\s+\n*|(:) *\n| +$/gm,"$1");
                //buscar si está el texto "ACTIVO" en el estado
                ok = /^Estado: *ACTIVO *$/m.test(res);
            } else
                res = "RUC: " + ruc + "\nNo existe.";
                
            //mostrar el texto formateado
            if (ok)
                existente.classList.add("ok");
            else 
                existente.classList.remove("ok");
            existente.innerText = res;
        }
    } //falta verificar errores en conexión
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

```css
#resultado, #existente {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#resultado.ok, #existente.ok {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<label>RUC:</label>
<input type="text" id="input_ruc" style="width:100%;"
       oninput="validarInput(this)"
       placeholder="Ingrese su RUC">
<pre id="resultado"></pre>
<pre id="existente"></pre>
```

[<kbd>Demo para móviles</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/marianom/wphzep59/3/)

---

#### Descripción:

El primer paso es eliminar los caracteres que no nos interesan (`-.,[]() \t\r\n\f`):

```js
var ruc = input.value.replace(/[-.,[\]()\s]+/g,"");
```

- dentro de los corchetes se puede agregar cualquier caracter que se quiera ignorar.

Luego, comprobamos que nos haya quedado un entero:

```js
if ((ruc = Number(ruc)) && ruc % 1 === 0) {
```

Y con el entero, llamamos a la función principal:

```js
rucValido(ruc);
```

Dentro de la función, vemos que sean 11 dígitos y que empiece en 10, 15, 16, 17 o 20:

```js
if (!(ruc >= 1e10 && ruc < 11e9
   || ruc >= 15e9 && ruc < 18e9
   || ruc >= 2e10 && ruc < 21e9)) {
```

Y, si se cumple todo lo anterior, podemos verificar que el último dígito (verificador) sea el correcto.

**¿Cómo se valida el dígito verificador de un RUC?**

La SUNAT utiliza una adaptación del método para códigos de control llamado [Módulo 11](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_de_control#M.C3.B3dulo_11) o [ISBN 10](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISBN#El_ISBN_de_diez_d.C3.ADgitos). Es un método muy utilizado en estos casos para detectar errores en un solo dígito, o intercambios simples o dobles (esencialmente, errores de tipeo). Consiste en:

1. Multiplicar cada uno de los primeros 10 dígitoa por un factor fijo, según su posición (el primer dígito por 5, el segundo por 4, *3, *2, *7, *6, *5, *4, *3, *2).
2. Sumar cada uno de los resultados del punto anterior.
3. Calcular el resto de dividirlo por 11 (`suma % 11`).
4. Obtener el complemento a 11 (`11 - resto`).
5. Verificar si el último dígito del punto anterior coincide con el último dígito del RUC (`if (ruc % 10 == complemento % 10)`).

[image: Diagrama ejemplificando los pasos]

Es decir que, para cada dígito, vamos a sumar el último dígito del RUC (`ruc % 10`) y multiplicarlo por su factor (`i % 7 + (i/7|0) + 1`) -sí, esto nos da 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, para cada valor de `i`.

En cada iteración de `i`, eliminamos el último dígito (`ruc = ruc/10|0`).

Cabe destacar que, para simplificar la operación aún más, incluímos el dígito verificador en la misma cuenta (con factor 1 para `i=0`). Sólo necesitamos ajustar en los casos que en el paso **4** se obtengan valores mayores a 9. Si es 10 u 11, significa que el último dígito es 0 o 1, y en esos casos se le resta 1 a la suma total (`suma = -(ruc%10<2)`).

Entonces nos queda:

```js
for (var suma = -(ruc%10<2), i = 0; i<11; i++, ruc = ruc/10|0)
    suma += (ruc % 10) * (i % 7 + (i/7|0) + 1);
```

Y se comprueba cuando:

```js
suma % 11 === 0;
```

Si esta última condición es verdadera, entonces se comprueba el dígito verificador, y el RUC es válido.

Comment: Muchas gracias Mariano!
Tu código me ayudo mucho. ¿En la function ***obtenerDatosSUNAT(ruc)***, cuál es la disponibilidad de consultas en este método? ¿Cuántas comprobaciones de datos puedo hacer? Saludos.

Comment: @Lucas es un servicio que no es mío, que está puesto sólo a modo de ejemplo. No lo sé... Te recomiendo contactarlos a ellos para preguntarles.

Comment: @Mariano Excelente trabajo

Comment: Gracias compita, me ayudo muchisimo a comprender.